# strip words after matching character

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file where there are some lines in the pattern. I want to remove text after `_`. How do I do that in unix?

```
x y z 1_2 3_4 5_6
```

I tried this command:

```
$ sed 's/_.*//'
```

but it returns:

```
x y z 1
```

however I want

```
x y z 1 3 5
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the pattern always `X_Y`, where `X` is digit and `Y` is a single digit also?

Comment: @fedorqui nope, they are digits but not single, it may be 123_456, 22_44 etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove every `_` + character:

```
$ echo "x y z 1_2 3_4 5_6" | sed 's/_\w//g'
x y z 1 3 5
```

or, if you want to remove up to a space, remove any nonspace characters:

```
sed 's/_[^ ]*//g'
```

Comment: @choroba thanks for the edit. `sed 's/_\w*//g'` would also make this (or `sed 's/_\w\+//g'` if things like `7_` want to be kept).

Comment: or if you're feeling POSIX-compliant, I'd suggest `s/_[^[:space:]]\{1,\}//g`

Comment: @TomFenech looking the sample maybe extend the class with coma `[^[:space:],]``

Comment: @Neron I can't see any commas in the input, so I'm not sure how that would help.

Comment: @TomFenech it is in the comment of the OP (the second), where poster give a real sample

Comment: @NeronLeVelu the OP is mentioning possible values, hence the commas; but it does not look like the string has commas in it.

Comment: OK, so comma is just to separate sample values and thus not to be added in class :-)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu this is my understanding. And since the OP accepted the answer, it must be the case.

Comment: Nice discussion, there were no comma, i used comma in comment just to separate values.